# Start Jenkins with JDK 8 without changing system java_home

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins 2.46.3 LTS version that i am trying to upgrade to 2.73.3 LTS version. My current java version is 1.7. How do i install and start Jenkins with 1.8 version? I am getting the following error after i copied Jenkins war file under (`/usr/lib/Jenkins`) and restarted the service

```
$ sudo service jenkins start
Starting Jenkins Jenkins requires Java8 or later, but you are running 1.7.0_97-b02 from /app_2/java/jdk1.7.0_97/jre
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 51.0
        at Main.main(Main.java:124)
```

Is there any way to start Jenkins using Java 8 without changing the system classpath?

Thanks,
Ann

Comment: How are you installing and running Jenkins? The answer will vary depending on your installation method and how to execute it.

Answer (score 2):

Set `JENKINS_JAVA` option in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file.

The variable name might be different depending on your operating system and package source but the `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file is usually the configuration file for your `jenkins` service.

Comment: @java13 if it helped can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just run the war with the new java binary:

```
nohup <path to your new jdk8 folder>/java -jar jenkins.war > $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

Not sure if JAVA_HOME is needed, but you can execute the line below in the shell, before the command above, or add to the top of init script :

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to your new jdk8 folder>/java
```

Hope that helps.